# Time Selector- Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to develop a time selector ui as given below. But i m not getting any idea what is the best approach to it. tried using lazy columns and android views but it was not customizable as the ui . Please refer to ui below and help to build it.Challenges faced was when srolled using a lazy column it will scrool so smooth.I need to build it like we have in system alarm apps and all

Thank you!
[image: Time selector ui.]

Comment: Ye ye ye... You need to use `Animatable`s/`AnimatedContent` here. Just have a look at AC it will help you out. Super easy, barely an inconvenience.

Comment: Can you pls tell how to handle scroll in that. I could not find any resource

Comment: Just apply `Modifier.verticalScroll()` or it's horizontal equivalent on the Composable you wish to make scrollable. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedcontent)

Comment: i think you are not clear about my question. please look into the ui. it should scroll like a list and should stop at the item only and not in any empty space. it will be helpfull if u can give a complete code. I am having no idea. I added time picker from xml with interoperabilty but its ui is not customisable cant set color to middle part

Comment: @HarishPadmanabh did you find best way to implement this type of animation in jetpack compose? if yes then please send the link of it that will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @heetkanabar no , still looking for a solution. For the time being i used normal time picker from xml

Comment: @HarishPadmanabh Btw I got the version which is 1.0.3 which is define define side of meven-central.